# Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal

Tags: netbeans

Estoy comenzando con netbeans, si bien inicialmente me iba bien, ahora al crear un nuevo archivo me sale siempre el siguiente error:

> Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal

```
/**
 *
 * @author 
 */

public class E2_VillarrealC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Dades Exercici");


    //Calculem el area LLARG X AMPLE de les piscines.
```

---

el error que me da:

> Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal E2_VillarrealC
>   /Users/macluu/Library/..../run.xml:53: Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED
>   (total time: 0 seconds)

¿Qué puede ser?

¡Gracias!

---

Os paso pantallazo, he creado la class pero no hay manera, el error sigue saliendo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error esta relacionado al paquete que defines en tu clase, revisa en donde se encuentra  y define un paquete correcto para tu clase principal, agregué respuesta @LourdesVCastillo saludos!

Answer (score 4):

El error mencionado:

> Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal

que se puede mostrar en inglés de esta forma:

> Error: Could not find or load main class

Se debe al paquete que defines en tu clase en la cual se debe encontrar la clase principal (que contiene  `main(String[] args)`), es incorrecto, por esa razón no la encuentra.

Como ejemplo:

Si tienes tu clase principal dentro del paquete com.myapp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debes definir en tu clase este paquete (`package com.myapp`):

```
package com.myapp;

public class E2_VillarrealC  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {       
            System.out.println("Ejercicio");    
    }

}
```

de otra forma, si defines un paquete diferente, incorrecto o en el cual no se encuentre la clase principal, obtendrás el error:

Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Cuando tienes una clase en una estructura de paquetes, java se espera encontrar ese fichero según esa estructura. Si la clase se encuentra en otro paquete debes importar la misma, por ejemplo:

```
package org.mipaquete;
import org.mipaquete.miclase;

class PruebaMiClase {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola te dejo como lo solucioné luego de tres meses de sufrimiento.

En el directorio donde tenía el proyecto había una carpeta en la ruta con tilde en el nombre "Programación".

Solo tuve que quitarle la tilde y listo, se me solucionó.

Espero te sirva o a alguien que estuvo buscando tanto tiempo como yo.

Saludos!

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Solo queria dejarlo para que alguein tenga otra opción si no le resultan las otras soluciones, como me psso a mí que estuve 3 meses estancado. Soy relativamente nuevo tanto en programación como en stackoverflow. Gracias y revisaré lo que me aconsejas. Saludos

Comment: Si eres desarrollador, primeramente no se deberían usar tildes o acentos en nombres de proyectos.

Answer (score 0):

Un motivo podría ser que el JRE que estás usando no esté consolidado (Unbound). Para ver si es el caso:

1.- Clic derecho a tu proyecto

2.- Properties

3.- Java BuildPath

4.- Libraries

5.- Ve que tu JRE no diga "Unbound"

6-. Si sí está en Unbound, clic en editar y elige un JRE que esté disponible

Con eso debería solucionarse el problema de que no encuentra la clase principal, si es que los paquetes están bien importados (import nombrepaquete.algo, por ejemplo), claro.